# Selecting contours error

Tags: python, opencv, contour, image-segmentation

I am working on the computer image processing project involving segmentation of the objects and I found the contours but I want to draw only some of them, for example, first one to further fill it with color. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Expected CvSeq for argument 'contour'.

Here is the piece of the code where error occurs.

```
mem=cv.CreateMemStorage()
nc=cv.FindContours(img_th,mem,cv.CV_RETR_LIST,cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,(0,0))  
c=nc[1]
cv.DrawContours(img_adth,c,cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0),cv.CV_RGB(0,255,0),2,2,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error from the drawing function.

I never used opencv python API, but I suppose unlike C++, C and python APIs have a different style of representing contours.

In C++, you can select a contour id and draw only that one. If you want to draw all the contours, you enter id = -1.

In C/Python you "point" the contour in the vector to draw only that one. So, contours (nc) is a pointer to the first contour. If you want to draw all the contours, you use a while(contours != null) loop.

To be more clear, I changed your code as such, try to use this one. I am not quiet sure, so let me know if this one works..

```
...
c = nc.next //until you select exact one
cv.DrawContours(img_adth,c,cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0),cv.CV_RGB(0,255,0),2,2,-1)
```